# pandasにて末尾."0"ゼロを削除をする方法

Tags: python, python3, pandas

やりたいこと
Excelからデータを読み込み,.0"ゼロを削除したいです。

Excelのデータ

```
   番号        番号2          備考   
123043449019　 0123479020    有  
            　 0123499020    無  
123043449020　               有
```

pythonのデータを読み込むとき

```
   番号         番号2          備考   
123043449019.0  0123479020     有  
            　  0123499020     無  
123043449020.0　               有
```

参考:
[pandas列の末尾の ".0"ゼロを丸める/削除する方法は？][1]

".0"を削除する方法、わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。

お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.read_excel("test.xls")
#### NaN を消す
df.fillna('',inplace=True)

#".0"ゼロを丸める/削除する

df['番号'] = df['番号'].astype(str)
df['番号'] = df['番号'].str.replace('.0','')

#print (df)

df_number = df["番号"]
df_no_hyphen=  df["番号2"]
df_existence=  df["番号3"]
df_cnt = len(df)
print(df.head())
```

現在の結果,すべての0が削除されます。

```
  番号         
1234344919
```

Comment: 参考のリンク先が設定されていませんが、[こちらでしょうか？](https://www.it-swarm-ja.com/ja/python/pandas%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E6%9C%AB%E5%B0%BE%E3%81%AE-0%E3%82%BC%E3%83%AD%E3%82%92%E4%B8%B8%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B%E5%89%8A%E9%99%A4%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%AF%EF%BC%9F/829602411/) / 元のページは [how to round/remove traling “.0” zeros in pandas column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42403907)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)の引数で`converters`を指定することでうまく行きました。
※Python 3.9.0環境で確認

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", converters={"番号":int}) # または{"番号":str}
print(df)

""" 
             番号          番号2 備考
0  123043449019  123479020.0  有
1           NaN  123499020.0  無
2  123043449020          NaN  有
"""
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。問題なく出来ました。
因みに`converters `で番号2の先頭に0を追加すること可能でしょうか。
`df['番号2'] = '0' + df['番号2'].astype(str)`こちらだと先頭に0を追加できましたが`converters `の方法でもあれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 手元の環境では`converters={"番号":int, "番号2":str}`に変更すると前ゼロを表示できますがいかがでしょうか。